# Flink + Kafka + Kerberos: Could not find a 'KafkaClient' entry in the JAAS configuration

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, kerberos, jaas

I am using Flink 1.8 trying to connect to a Kerberized Kafka Broker.

I am setting KafkaClient entry in jaas.conf like following:

```
KafkaClient {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    useTicketCache=true
    renewTicket=true
    serviceName="kafka";
};
Client {  
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
   useTicketCache=true
   renewTicket=true
   serviceName="zookeeper";
};
```

and pointing to that jaas files by setting this property in the code, which is passed to the Kafka Consumer with the rest of the required properties (bootstrap.servers, etc)...

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", args[0]);
properties.setProperty("security.protocol", "SASL_PLAINTEXT");
properties.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config","/usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/conf/kafka_client_jaas.conf");
```

I also tried to specify jaas.conf path on KAFKA_OPTS environment variable before launching the flink app.

The error I am getting is:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a 'KafkaClient'
>   entry in the JAAS configuration. System property
>   'java.security.auth.login.config' is
>   /tmp/jaas-6335181385007718768.conf

I don't know if jaas.conf file should by put in temporary file automatically or it is not detecting well the specified config file. The temporary files is deleted after error occurs but there are some files on tmp from previous launchs, they do not contain any code (only some default comments and empty configuration).

Comment: To get some debug-level logging from JAAS, add `-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true` and `-Djava.security.debug=gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser,logincontext` >> but that will not explain how that temp file is created and forced into JAAS in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in the setup; First, passing jaas conf file location and then jaas conf file content

**java.security.auth.login.config** is system property. So you should pass either by setting system property in code

```
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "/usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/conf/kafka_client_jaas.conf");
```

or by setting JVM argument -D while running.

```
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/conf/kafka_client_jaas.conf
```

jaas file entry should be configured either to use keytabs or username/password

**kafka-keytab-auth-jaas.conf**

```
KafkaClient {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    useKeyTab = true   
    useTicketCache=false
    storeKey = true
    keyTab="/tmp/kafka.service.keytab"
    principal="****@REALM"
    serviceName="kafka";
};
```

**kafka-password-auth-jaas.conf**

```
KafkaClient {
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
  username="user"
  password="userpassword";
};
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. But using "java.security.auth.login.config" in code, the errror says that KafkaClient entry could not be found in the temporary jaas file inside /tmp, it is not reading the content of the jaas.conf file specified in the code (it is the first thing I tried). I finally get it working by putting the KafkaClient config inline inside the code (instead of putting the file location,I wrote the different entries in jaas config in a single line, with a blank between each of them).